# Is anyone there who can help me about obfuscated code

Tags: javascript, decode, obfuscation, deobfuscation

Any who can help me to make this code right, Thank You

```
 slot1 = _0xae1f[9];
 slot2 = _0xae1f[9];

 slotname = (Math[_0xae1f[10]]() <= 0.5) ? slot1 : slot2;

 e[_0xae1f[11]] = _0xae1f[12] + h + _0xae1f[13] + slotname + _0xae1f[14] + w + _0xae1f[15];
```

Comment: `_0xae1f` looks like an array, but it is not declared anywhere in your snippet.

Comment: do you recognize any part of this code? http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=943a087fd79b9e0ec1cedebf90f6b8a0

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is code missing? From that what you postet, the explanation of the code would be:

1. Line: slot1 gets value of index 9 of _oxae1f array.
2. Line: slot2 gets value of index 9 of _oxae1f array.
3. Line: if the index 10 of _oxae1f array is lower or equal 0.5, then slotname gets value of slot1, if not: slotname gets value of slot2
4. Line: array e at index _oxae1f[11] gets value of the sum of all the other values.

to make this code right, you should rename the properties maybe? Is there more code?

Comment: `_0xae1f[10]` is most likely 'random', so it will use `Math.random()` to assign either `slot1` or `slot2` to `slotname`

Comment: Light 
can you please help me more about this, send me pm please tommonazi at gmail dot com

Comment: I have mostly ready
but it not read slot2

  slot1 = "slotone";
  slot2 = "slottwo";
  slotname = Math.random() ? slot1 : slot2;

Comment: you need the condition after your random-method. in your original code it is asked if Math.random() is lover/equal to 0.5. if yes -> slot1 - if no -> slot2....
Math.random() results in a number between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have mostly ready
but it not read slot2

```
 slot1 = "slotone";
 slot2 = "slottwo";
 slotname = Math.random() ? slot1 : slot2;
```